# Why do objects need to implement Iterable<T> to be the target of for-each loops, if it requires no implementation?

Tags: java, iterable

Why do objects need to implement Iterable to be the target of for-each loops, if it does not require implementing any methods?
Couldn't this be done automatically at compile time whenever an object is used in a for-each loop?

Comment: _if it does not require implementing any methods?..._ Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: What methods do you think don't need to be implemented? For an object to be iterable it needs to provide an iterator. Are you perhaps looking at a class that already provides an implementation?

Comment: Voted to close, since the question is based on a misunderstanding, thinking that `Iterable` doesn't have any unimplemented methods, when in fact method [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator--) is unimplemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Iterable require the class to implement the method Iterator iterator().

It is not an empty interface.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: My bad. I was reading a summary on Iterable and tested it in a random class in a project I have, I expected a warning from Eclipse to implement required methods, but none showed. Turns out it was an abstract class so no warning was given. :-)